# How can I use two WHERE in a command

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I want to run below command in my SQL database to delete links of a particular user between a particular date range:

```sql
DELETE FROM `links`
WHERE `user_id` = 83238 AND
      `created` BETWEEN `2018-12-07 00:00:00` AND `2018-12-08 23:59:59`;
```

But it doesn't works.

Comment: "It doesn't work" -- Do you mean there's an error? What's the error?

Comment: It says - #1054 - Unknown column '2018-12-07 00:00:00' in 'where clause'

Comment: Don't use backticks to enclose text or datetime values, use quotes `'`

Comment: like @forpas said but better is to drop using the backticks all the way to made your query ANSI SQL valid meaning you can port it between database vendors when needed.

Comment: @RaymondNijland it seems that the OP did not use even backticks. These were added by Shadow while editing.

Comment: yes i now notice i didn't check normally nobody edites topicstarters code like that to answer the question @forpas not sure Shadow did this..Because no MySQL keywords and reserved words are used in the column or table names..